# Android SplashScreen theme uses a lot of memory

Tags: android, memory, xamarin, android-theme

My app used a lot of memory right after the launch of my activity.

First I had a Theme to place an image in my splashScreen, but because I wanted to debug, I placed this in code. After research with the Android Device monitor and a few debug tests I found this line to cause a huge memory usage of 25 MB.

```
Window.SetBackgroundDrawableResource (Resource.Drawable.splash);
```

The jpeg of the splashscreen is only 16 kB. Does anyone know why this way of loading an image uses so much memory and how I can reduce it?

Comment: I'm working in Xamarin Android which *should* be irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @downvoter care to explain?

Comment: Keep in mind that jpeg is much more efficient than Android's actual in memory representation of an image. My understanding is that the in memory size of any image (jpeg, png, etc.) requires `pixel width * pixel height * 4' bytes. Does that help explain the memory usage any? This size increase is because displaying an image requires inflating it back to Bitmap size and jpeg is much, much more size efficient than Bitmap.

Comment: With that being said, I have no idea if Android will scale the image or anything else to optimize the displaying of it when you use it as a splash screen. But a simple 1280x1280 image loaded in memory with no optimizations will require ~6.5MB (as an example).

Comment: What is your memory usage if you load the background from an XML?

Answer (score 1):

I've done splash-screens or, as I like to call it, branded launch screen in the past and didn't have memory issues. Check [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@aitorvs/android-app-with-branded-launch-screen-31ffd8a9d1da#.bauhj83tn) I posted in Medium some ago. At the end of it you'll also find the [link](https://github.com/aitorvs/BrandedLaunch) to the GitHub example project.

Hope this helps solving your problem.